# App freezes at splash screen on mobile device, not on FlashBuilder's emulator

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, build, autocomplete, compilation

I want to include Mobile AutoCompleteCombobox made by Flextras (http://www.Flextras.com), into my project to give to user a rapid way to fill some textInput. So I integrated it sucessfully in my code, I can tell that because the result is nice when I launch FlexBuilder's mobile device simulator : It launch my app code to test it including the component (I used the sample code provided into sources). 
After that test, I wanted an apk file to test this app under a real mobile device. So I builded successfully the swf and finally the apk files ! But my app fails when I launch it under mobile device : It freezed at my splash picture for unlimited time ! Have you ever seen this problem and have you even resolved this one ? Because I searched in the big exchange forum which is named Stackoverflow.com, but I can't find any similar issue !

Please could you give me a way to be efficient ?
This following lines are here to explain two parts of my method : firstly to compile swf Flex file, secondly to build the apk Android package.

1) Launched with cmd.exe console, to compile :

> ant -buildfile Build_myAppProject.xml actionCompiler

2) Launched with cmd.exe console, to build the app file :

> adt -package -target apk -storetype pkcs12 -keystore [MyCertificateFile.p12] -storepass hyebiell1234 [MyOutputFile.apk]  [MyAppInfoDescriptor.xml] [MyAppCompiledFile.swf] -extdir [MyANEAndLibrariesFolder] -C src\assets  -C src\assets\img -e src[MySqliteFileToCopyIntoPackage] [MySqliteFileToCopyIntoPackage] -e src\icone50x50.png icone50x50.png -e src\icone72x72.png icone72x72.png -e src\icone128x128.png icone128x128.png -e src\icone144x144.png icone144x144.png -e src\icone512x512.png icone512x512.png

ant_build_myAppProject.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project name="Build_avec_4.11_AIR_4.0" basedir=".">
    <property name="FLEX_HOME" value="c:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash Builder 4.5/sdks/4.11_AIR_4.0"/>
    <property name="APP_ROOT" value="src"/>
    <property name="ANE_DIR" value="extensions"/>
    <taskdef resource="flexTasks.tasks" classpath="${FLEX_HOME}/Ant/lib/flexTasks.jar"/>
    <target name="actionCompiler">
        <mxmlc 
            file="${APP_ROOT}/myAppProject.mxml" 
            output="${APP_ROOT}/myAppProject.swf"
            locale="fr_FR"
            static-rsls="true"
            accessible="true"
            configname="airmobile"
            debug="false"
            failonerror="true" 
            optimize="true"
            maxmemory="512m"
            swf-version="16"
        >
            <source-path path-element="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks"/>
            <source-path path-element="${APP_ROOT}"/>
            <compiler.external-library-path dir="${ANE_DIR}" includes="*.swc" append="true"/>
            <library-path dir="${ANE_DIR}" includes="*.swc,*ane" append="true"/>
            <library-path dir="${FLEX_HOME}/frameworks/locale/fr_FR" includes="*.swc" append="true"/>
            <define name="CONFIG::device" value="false"/>
            <define name="CONFIG::iphone" value="false"/>
            <define name="CONFIG::android" value="true"/>
        </mxmlc>
    </target>
</project>
```

Lately I launched the app with LogCat and I get this :

```
12-11 16:19:51.087: D/action(2224): android.intent.action.MAIN
12-11 16:19:51.158: D/cym(2224): cancelUnReadCount(ComponentInfo{air.PlanifVisites/air.PlanifVisites.AppEntry})
12-11 16:19:51.168: D/cym(2224): onInvokeApp(0)
12-11 16:19:51.188: I/ActivityManager(376): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=air.PlanifVisites/.AppEntry bnds=[129,38][240,197] u=0} from pid 2224
12-11 16:19:51.288: D/dalvikvm(376): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1533K, 37% free 9768K/15495K, paused 72ms, total 80ms
12-11 16:19:51.338: I/ActivityManager(376): Start proc air.PlanifVisites for activity air.PlanifVisites/.AppEntry: pid=4942 uid=10087 gids={3003, 1015, 1028}
12-11 16:19:51.398: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
12-11 16:19:51.398: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <GetImageAttributes:1158>: RGBX_8888
12-11 16:19:51.438: E/Trace(4942): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
12-11 16:19:51.518: I/StartupTime1(4942): :1449847191530
12-11 16:19:51.538: D/dalvikvm(4942): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries
12-11 16:19:51.698: D/dalvikvm(4942): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.adobe.air/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x40e213e0
12-11 16:19:51.728: D/dalvikvm(4942): Added shared lib /data/data/com.adobe.air/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x40e213e0
12-11 16:19:51.728: D/dalvikvm(4942): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.adobe.air/lib/libstlport_shared.so 0x40e213e0, skipping init
12-11 16:19:51.728: D/dalvikvm(4942): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.adobe.air/lib/libCore.so 0x40e213e0
12-11 16:19:51.968: D/dalvikvm(4942): Added shared lib /data/data/com.adobe.air/lib/libCore.so 0x40e213e0
12-11 16:19:52.078: V/Sensors(376): int poll__setDelay(sensors_poll_device_t*, int, int64_t)
12-11 16:19:52.078: V/Sensors(376): int sensors_poll_context_t::setDelay(int, int64_t)
12-11 16:19:52.078: V/Sensors(376): int poll__setDelay(sensors_poll_device_t*, int, int64_t)
12-11 16:19:52.078: V/Sensors(376): int sensors_poll_context_t::setDelay(int, int64_t)
12-11 16:19:53.470: D/dalvikvm(4942): GC_CONCURRENT freed 3257K, 52% free 4080K/8451K, paused 3ms+2ms, total 62ms
12-11 16:19:53.520: D/StartupTime2(4942): :1449847193331
12-11 16:19:53.520: I/__BUILD_NO(4942): #15.0.0.349
12-11 16:19:53.780: I/Choreographer(4942): Skipped 104 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 16:19:53.820: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
12-11 16:19:53.820: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
12-11 16:19:53.820: I/ActivityManager(376): Displayed air.PlanifVisites/.AppEntry: +2s529ms
12-11 16:19:54.471: D/dalvikvm(4942): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 468K, 55% free 3833K/8451K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
12-11 16:19:54.471: I/dalvikvm-heap(4942): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.438MB for 1463056-byte allocation
12-11 16:19:54.491: I/Choreographer(4942): Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
12-11 16:19:54.501: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
12-11 16:19:54.501: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <GetImageAttributes:1158>: RGBX_8888
12-11 16:19:54.501: I/ggheart(2224): onStop
12-11 16:19:54.501: I/Test(2224): onStop
12-11 16:20:00.036: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <CreateImage:893>: Android Image
12-11 16:20:00.036: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(118): <GetImageAttributes:1102>: RGBA_8888
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you run it on the device in debug mode?  Also, what do you see in LogCat when you try to run your app?

Comment: I've append the log from LogCat into the first post.

Comment: "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." sounds like some kind of infinite loop ? As Brian said, try to debug it on your Android device, I doubt it is because of the AutoCompleteCombobox component. And try to build the apk directly in the FlashBuilder (Project > Export release build) - maybe there is something wrong with your build process ?